# Issue with bash while loop

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, printf

So I've got a loop

```
while read line
do
    printf $line"\n"
done < file.txt
```

And this prints each line on a new line (like the original file).
Yet when I do

```
while read line
do
    printf $line
done < file.txt
```

it doesn't print anything when I would expect it to put all the lines together.

(For extra info: I'm just seeing how the loop works because I got a file of numbers on each line and I want to apply the same operation to each number then sum them up)

Comment: I suggest to use `printf "%s\n" "$line"` or `printf "%s" "$line"`. See `help -m printf`.

Comment: I get the same issue. With \n it prints each line, without it it prints nothing. Could it be because I set IFS='\n' earlier in the script?

Answer (score 1):

printf is documented like this:

```
SYNOPSIS
     printf format [arguments ...]
```

The first argument (i.e. the first word on each line of file.txt in your case) is being interpreted as a format string, so it's not doing what you expect.  You need

```
while read line
do
    printf "%s" "$line"
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it prints, but you don't see it.

If this is all what gets printed in your program, you end up with a (possibly long) line being output, but without a trailing newline. Now, back on your shell, the shell displays its prompt. Likely, this prompt erases from your terminal the line which you have just printed.

To verify it, redirect the stdout to a file, and then use a tool such as `less` or `wc` or `od` to look at the contents of your file.